# How can I animate a route path on a custom map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, maps, polyline

I would like to overlay a dynamic route path on a custom geographical map image in a web application. The path displaying the route should dynamically fill (and animate on page load) with a different colour as the user achieves their distance goal. An example might be:

- User browses to map page
- World map displays with a route overlay
  showing e.g. London-> Cairo -> LA -> London
- Page finishes loading.
- JS calculates how much of total distance user has covered (from server
  side data)
- overlay line fills in a different colour gradually (animated - think Indiana Jones!)

I'm liking leaflet maps ([leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/)) for the map tiles and possibly Raphael to draw and animate the polylines.

The initial version will be quite simple with a predefined route so I will know the coordinates of the the cities up front. My question is how can I animate polylines added to a leaflet (or other) map? Would Raphael be appropriate for his?

Comment: You might get better answers at http://gis.stackexchange.com/, a stackexchange site dedicated for questions about geographical information systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay the map image with a canvas and draw the route on the canvas.
You can use it also in the admin as a pin placing method, just handle canvas click events and store the x,y, coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/), and check out [geoserver](http://geoserver.org) for your back-end.

Comment: I've updated my question which will hopefully better explain what I want to do. It's more of a front-end problem and I only really need a world map with one or two zoom layers to start with.